# Delphi MS ScriptControl не дает посимвольно перебирать строки

Tags: javascript, строки, delphi

Нужно исполнить JS-код в паскале
Но, как уже написал в заголовке, библиотека ScriptControl не хочет выдавать строку посимвольно

Делаю так: В `public` основной формы записываю `js: OleVariant;` далее так:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  js := CreateOleObject('ScriptControl');
  js.Language := 'JScript';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
Memo4.Text := js.Eval(Memo3.Text);
end;
```

В итоге с тестами без посимвольного перебора строк вроде бы все нормально

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s.slice(0,1)
```

Выдает `r` (см фото 1)

Но такой код

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s[0]
```

Выдает пустоту, а к тому же такая проверка

```
var s = 'rtfm'
s[0]==undefined
```

Выдает `true` (См фото 2 и 3)

В чем может быть проблема и как с ней бороться?

P.S. Похожая штука была и с тем, что не определен объект JSON, и соответственно, плюшки, подобные JSON.parse были недоступны. Но я взял исходник JSON-а [отсюда](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.2/json3.min.js). Так что если вдруг (что очень вряд ли) у кого-то есть доступ к исходнику такого примитива, как String, то поделитесь)))

[image: Фото 1]

[image: Фото 2]

[image: Фото 3]

Comment: Чтобы оно просто работало, сделал такое `String.prototype.toArray = function(i){
 var res = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < this.toString().length; i++){
  res.push(this.toString().substr(i,1))
 }
 return res;
}` и беру `s.toArray()[i]`

Comment: Видать IE не поддерживает такую фишку

Comment: Может есть способ обновить msscript.ocx, чтоб оно поддерживало IE8+?